# How to specify Boost location for CMake in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: boost, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to use CMake in Visual Studio 2017 but it's not finding Boost. I think this is normal but previously I'd use CMake GUI to specify BOOST_ROOT. Where can I specify the location in Visual Studio 2017 without editing the CMake files themselves (which are stored in source control so shouldn't be edited)?

Answer (score 5):

If you go to CMake->Change CMake Settings->CMakeLists.txt this opens CMakeSettings.json. You should see something like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "x86-Debug",
            "generator": "Visual Studio 15 2017",
            "configurationType": "Debug",
            "buildRoot": "${env.LOCALAPPDATA}\\CMakeBuild\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
            "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
            "buildCommandArgs": "\"-m -v:minimal\"."
        },
```

You can add customisation by adding variables:

```
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "x86-Debug",
        "generator": "Visual Studio 15 2017",
        "configurationType": "Debug",
        "buildRoot": "${env.LOCALAPPDATA}\\CMakeBuild\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
        "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
        "buildCommandArgs": "\"-m -v:minimal\".",
        "variables": [
            {
                "name": "BOOST_ROOT",
                "value": "C:\\boost_1_63_0"
            }
        ]
    },
```

When you save this file Visual Studio will automatically rerun CMake, or select CMake->Generate Cache.

I don't want to have per-build variables so this seems to work:

```
{
    "variables": [
        {
            "name": "BOOST_ROOT",
            "value": "C:\\boost_1_63_0"
        }
    ],
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "x86-Debug",
            "generator": "Visual Studio 15 2017",
            "configurationType": "Debug",
            "buildRoot": "${env.LOCALAPPDATA}\\CMakeBuild\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
            "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
            "buildCommandArgs": "\"-m -v:minimal\"."
        },
```

See here for more details:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/#configure-cmake

Comment: The common variables version didn't work for me, but the per-build variables did. Thanks!